# Would it be accurate to draw a similarity between the role of MP and a Company Director?

Tags: united-kingdom

Would it be accurate to draw a similarity between the role of MP accountable to the electorate and a Company Director accountable to shareholders?

Comment: Not quite sure how "fair" or "unfair" could come into this.  "Fair" to whom? If it is your analogy, then go for it.

Comment: @Alexei Before your edit OP already switched "fair" to "accurate" which does not depend on how one defines what is fair.

Comment: @Miech - ok, I have rolled back to OP's revision. Thanks.

Comment: @Alexei I'm of the opinion that your edit changed meaning significantly, however was an interesting question in it's own right. No matter if it is or it's not accurate to draw similarity between MP and company director, there might be some similarities.

Comment: @Miech - anyway this question remains the same and I will ask that question after doing a little bit of research.

Answer (score 3):

No, for two major reasons.

1. Country has no (or at least is not supposed to have) profit motive. Companies exist to maximise monetary gain of owners/shareholders. States are supposed to maximise well-being of citizens which requires presence of public education, public healthcare, infrastructure maintenance, working civil service, fair judiciary, retirement pensions, legal customer protections, worker rights and many other things that run directly contrary to "maximising profit" of the state.
2. Company directors or board of directors is not accountable to workers. This is akin to state disenfranchising entirety of workforce. That was usual "feature" of slavery.

Comment: "Company limited by guarantee" and other nonprofit structures exist.

Comment: @pjc50 According to wiki "In British and Irish company law, a company limited by guarantee (LBG) is an alternative type of corporation used primarily for non-profit organisations that require legal personality." so while called "company" it doesn't have shareholders. It doesn't match spirit nor letter of question.

Comment: It does not have shareholders. It does, however, have directors - I was one for a while.

Comment: Question asks about "Company Director accountable to shareholders" as potential comparison to MP's being accountable to citizens. Question explicitly mentions shareholders, who implicitly hold shares for profit. Your suggestion, related to nonprofit organisations, is irrelevant to both explicit and implicit meaning of the question.

Answer (score 1):

> "All models are false, but some are useful"

Does the analogy hold? Well, it depends what you want to use it for. What's the company analogue of an Opposition MP? What's the analogue of a constituency? Are the public "shareholders" in this analogy? People can be banned from being directors for misconduct but cannot be banned from being MPs. Parties are critical to MPs but mostly irrelevant to directors.

You could argue that Cabinet members correspond to executive directors and MPs correspond to non-executive directors.

Comment: "People... cannot be banned from being MPs". I'm not sure what you mean by this. In quite a few European countries the right to stand for office can be curtailed by a court decision and it's sometimes done e.g. after a conviction of a politician (for corruption etc.)

Comment: There are quite a number of disqualifying behaviours (and jobs) or people considering standing as an MP. At least some of them are for *electoral* misconduct https://www.electoralcommission.org.uk/__data/assets/pdf_file/0019/173017/UKPGE-Part-1-Can-you-stand-for-election.pdf

Comment: @origimbo: Thanks for digging that. The UK does have something like I mentioned in the Representation of the People Act 1983. "The disqualification for a
corrupt practice begins from the date a person has been reported guilty by an election court or convicted and lasts for five years. " It also has quite a few other provisions/laws that disqualify someone from standing for MP.